# Ubuntu environment variables - Anaconda Jupyter

Tags: python, ubuntu, environment-variables, anaconda

I can launch Anaconda Jupyter notebook in two different ways (case A and case B below):

Case A.

1) I have the following code in .sh file, which is executable:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "/home/alex/Project"
"/home/alex/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook"
```

2) Or the following code in .sh file, which is executable:

```
"/home/alex/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook"
```

It both above cases the following Python (in Jupyter) command generates error:

```
import os
print(os.environ['CLASSPATH'])
```

Error:

```
KeyError: 'CLASSPATH'
```

Case B

1) I open terminal and type `jupyter-notebook` or `jupyter notebook`

2) I open terminal and type `/home/alex/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook`

In this case the same Python (in Jupyter) command returns correct value for `CLASSPATH`.

Does anybody know what is wrong and how I can start troubleshooting?

**Addition:** I set up `CLASSPATH` using the following command `sudo gedit ~/.bashrc`

Comment: You probably set `CLASSPATH` in your bash/zsh/sh-profile, either globally or locally. When executing `jupyter-notebook` from a terminal, your environment was set up by your shell, probably including `CLASSPATH`. When you execute a shellscript outside of an interactive shell, your environment is not loaded. Find out where `CLASSPATH` is set and make sure to get that into your script.

Comment: from your home directory do `echo $CLASSPATH` and then from inside the Jupyter shell do `!echo $CLASSPATH`, what do they return?

Comment: @user2722968 I added line to my post, so when I execute file, how can I make sure that correct `bashrc` is read?

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy. In terminal I get `CLASSPATH` back in Jupyter (case A) I get nothing back and in (Case B) I get correct path back

Comment: You could simply add `source $HOME/.bashrc` to your script

Comment: @user2722968 I added your line, but still same error in Jupyter

Answer (score 1):

```
print (os.environ)
```

Will show you **all** the values from `os`, but you're probably interested in

```
print(os.getenv('CLASSPATH'))
```